# Issue with macro in RTE (Rich Text Editor)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I got an issue with macro's in v7.2.6

When I put in 2 macros, it looks alright before saving:

```
<div class="umb-macro-holder Youtube mceNonEditable umb-macro-mce_8"><!-- <?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="Youtube" YoutubeEmbedURL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WMa-tyTTHSs" /> --><ins>Macro alias: <strong>Youtube</strong></ins></div>
<div class="umb-macro-holder Youtube mceNonEditable umb-macro-mce_9"><!-- <?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="Youtube" YoutubeEmbedURL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WMa-tyTTHSs" /> --><ins>Macro alias: <strong>Youtube</strong></ins></div>
```

But after saving it now looks like this, and messes up everything else there might be in the RTE:

```
<div class="umb-macro-holder mceNonEditable"><!-- <?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="Youtube" YoutubeEmbedURL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WMa-tyTTHSs" />
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="Youtube" YoutubeEmbedURL="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WMa-tyTTHSs" /> --> <ins>Macro alias: <strong>Youtube</strong></ins></div>
```

Anyone experiencing the same and might have a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bug in 7.2.6. Downgraded and it worked.

Tested it on fresh install without luck. Nyt downgrading to 7.2.2 fixes it.